# Need to Update External References in an Excel Sheet while a Macro is Running

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have an excel macro that sets Cells to an external location.

```
Range(NamedReference) = "='http://webaddress/ExcelSheet.xlsx'!NamedReference
```

Other cells use that location to calculate new values.

```
"A1" = NamedReference + 1
```

The problem is that I need to read the new calculated values back into the macro to export data, but the external link has not yet been calculated to any value. It is a #NAME? until the macro is done running. Is there any way to force excel to get those values during the macro run time?

I have tried a variety of things including

```
Calculate
CalculateFull
```

Any help would be appreciated. My current solution is to just close the macro on error and have the user re run the macro, but it is really kludgey.

**Edit: Forgot equals sign in formula

Comment: I've never tried reading straight from a web server before. It is a possibility to download the excel document from the web server into a temp directory on the computer, and delete when you've finished? I don't know if this will make any difference, just a suggestion.

Comment: @joshhendo Tried having the file open while this was running. It had no effect. This needs to run on multiple computers so saving locally isn't an option. Thanks for the suggestion though. It got me thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
```

See on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff195741.aspx)

Comment: No go, Thanks for the help though.